# sqlite-net-pcl C# как получить данные из определенного столбца из базы данных?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

у меня есть локальная база данных создал на основе этой статьи https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/databases

моя цель получить все данные из таблицы, вот так это делаю 
`var listdata = await App.Database.GetItemsAsyncB();`

теперь мне нужно чтобы в переменной `listsT` оказались все данные из конкретного столбца

и подскажите пожалуйста как выглядит это `{Binding Name}` на C# - думаю это мне поможет в решении задачи

В проекте все сделано как примере выше на сайте майкрософт.
Сейчас, добавил еще один новый метод для работы с базой данных

```
public Task<List<TodoItem>> GetItemsAsyncName()
{
  return database.QueryAsync<TodoItem>("SELECT * [Name] FROM [TodoItem]");
}
```

и вызываю этот метод вот так `var listdata = await App.Database.GetItemsAsyncName();`

Возможно я запрос не правильно составил этот `"SELECT * [Name] FROM [TodoItem]"`
подскажите как правильно?

Comment: `все данные из конкретного столбца` - `var listdata = await App.Database.GetItemsAsyncB().Select(x=>x.МойСтолбец);`

Comment: как выглядит это `{Binding Name}` на C# - так и выглядит

Comment: Task<List<TodoItem>> не содержит определения "Select", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "Select", принимающий тип "Task<List<TodoItem>>" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку). в проекте используется ```using SQLite;```

Comment: `var listdata = (await App.Database.GetItemsAsyncB()).Select(x=>x.МойСтолбец);`

Comment: это сработало. теперь в переменной listdata значение ```System.Linq.Enumerable SelectListIterator`2[App9.Models.TodoItem,System.String]``` а как получить данные? к примеру в массиве или строкой.

Comment: это и есть данные. Вы их уже получили

Comment: ну в базе хранятся имена, саша, фёдор и т.д вот как получить их к примеру в массиве? На деле имена(саша,фёдор) нужно отправить post запросом, что успешно реализовано, но приходят в пост запросе вот это ```System.Linq.Enumerable SelectListIterator`2[App9.Models.TodoItem,System.String]``` за место имён.

Comment: `var listdata = (await App.Database.GetItemsAsyncB()).Select(x=>x.МойСтолбец).ToArray();`